# How do I cancel Mac OS X install halfway through?

Tags: macos, installation

I'm installing OS X 10.4.5 from the original media, but have discovered halfway through (after the computer reboots into the new install and uses Disk 2) that the second disk is faulty, so I can't get past some of the non-essential software installs - it fails with an IO error reading the DVD, so I get stuck in an installer loop as it wants to restart/retry again and again.

I've managed to load up a Terminal and Finder from this point (Install Log -> Print -> Add Printer -> Printer Setup Help -> click on www.apple.com -> Safari -> use telnet: url to lauch Terminal -> run /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock).

But now I need to find out how to prevent the Installer.app running when I start the computer up; I'd just like to have it go to the normal login screen instead. I guess there's a configuration file or setting that indicates that it hasn't finished installing yet. Any ideas where such an item might be, so I can modify it?

Comment: Phew, I'm not too familiar with the installation procedure – but maybe it's related to the `.AppleSetupDone` file created when you've clicked through the setup ([this](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/10/forgot-mac-password-how-to-reset-mac-password/)), and if you [recreate it](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=84825) the system would think you're finished. I really don't know for 10.4 though, I've never installed it.